# Problems adding Jar files to Android Studio project

Tags: android, jar

I apologise for asking a question to which there are many pages offering answers, but I cannot match up any of the instructions and videos with what I am seeing on the screen!

I am using Android Studio 1.0.2 on Windows 7. I have created a basic app and want to add a jar file. All the instructions say 'Copy the jar to the libs folder'. There isn't one! One video I watched showed creating a 'libs' folder under the project but when I right-click, there is no 'new folder' option like in the video!

[image: What I can see]

The 'Folder' option here has a whole load of further options, none of them like the video tutorial. So what is the proper procedure in my clearly unique position of a perfectly new install and empty project?!?! Exactly what do I right-click on in the image above and what option do I choose? Feel free to treat me like an idiot!

Comment: You're in `packages` mode. In the Project view, at the top, click 'packages', and choose 'Project'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Niek said, you need to switch over to Project View.

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

Once there you will find the libs folder. Copy and paste the JAR into that folder and you should be all set! If you have issues after this post your build.gradle file.

Comment: Many thanks! Followed Ranjith's suggestion, and then the mode change one, and there it is. I am a VisualStudio/C# guy so all this Android Studio / Java etc is new to me. Apologies for asking stupid questions!

Answer (score -1):

Click on app>then New>Select New Module and you get a screen name "New Module". In this screen in the bottom select "Import .JAR or .AAR Package".

[image]